# Are the following sets isomorphic or have the same order type?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

> Are the following sets isomorphic or have the same order type ?
>
> 1. $(\mathbb R, \le) ,\ (\mathbb R,\ge)$
> 2. $(\mathbb Q, \le), \ (\mathbb R, \le) $
> 3. $(\mathbb N,\ge ), \ (\mathbb N,\le)$
> 4. $\omega+\omega, \ \omega\cdot\omega$

So in order to show they're isomorphic I need to find an injective function.

1. They are, there is no maximal/minimal element, both have the same cardinality. the function is $f(x)=x $.
2. No, they have different cardinality (is that enough?).
3. I think they aren't since one have a minimal element while the other does not.
4. Both have the same cardinality but the elements are different: one is {1,2,3...1',2'...} the other is {(0,1),(0,2)...} but I think there could be an injection.

Comment: I have a feeling that I answered that last one a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need $f(x)=-x$ instead.
2. Yes. So there cannot be any bijection, much less isomorphism.
3. You're correct.
4. Simpler argument appear to be $\omega+\omega=\omega\cdot2<\omega\cdot\omega$

Comment: About 4. so if one is smaller what does that tell us about isomorphism ?

Comment: There is no isomorphism. $\omega+\omega$ would be a proper subset of $\omega\cdot\omega$.